# how to have rest api client in my web portal - angular 6

Tags: angular, rest, api

I am trying to build a test portal , with in that portal  I would like 
to have a simple postman type app as a page where i can send http requests to 3 rd party clients and get response . from response value want to do other functions.
instead of me building from scratch is there any tool which i can easily integrate with angular 6

I have searched a lot but not able to get any direction
any direction will be helpful

Comment: Is the http client what you're looking for? https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: What tool are you looking for exactly? And do you have your own angular 6 application? Or you just want to test your api's by creating new angular application?

Answer (score 2):

https://angular.io/guide/http will do the magic.

Importing HttpClientModule inside of app.module.ts and declaring variable inside of service or component class in constructor. e.g.:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
ngOnInit(){
 this.http.HTTP_METHOD(params).subscribe(...)
}
```